# preg_match on hostname

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, expression

I'm trying to make a regular expression that matches on hostname in the url.
I want it to hit on de following hostnames:
- www.site.nl
- site.nl

I want it to return site.nl

I got this working with the following regex:
(?(?<=www.))site.(?:nl|be|eu)

However when I use this regex on something.site.nl it also returns site.nl. This is not what I want.
I only want a match when there is nothing before site.nl or when there's www. before it.

I've tried a lot of different expressions but can't figure out how I could do this.

I hope my question is clear and you guys can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^(?:www\.)?(site\.(?:nl|be|eu))$
```

should work.

(Don't forget the special meaning of dot in REs...)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
However this is still not what I want to accomplish.

With your regex I still get a match on site.nl in something.site.nl.
I only want a match on site.nl when there is nothing or www. before it.

Comment: What do you mean? What doesn't work? I haven't tested it in PHP which I don't have at hand right now, but I tested it in a regex checker and it accepts site.nl, www.site.nl and rejects foo.site.nl and similar.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this:

```
/^(www\.)?(site\.(nl|be|eu))$/
```